# convex polygon triangulation

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-geometry, triangulation

Suppose we have given a convex polygon on $n$ vertices $P= \{ a_1, \cdots , a_n \}$ in the plane (arranged clockwise). How can we prove that there exist atleast two indices $i$ such that circle $a_{i-1} a_i  a_{i+1}$ contains $P$?

Can someone give me an idea for to prove it?

Comment: Do you mean the circle passing through the points $a_{i-1}, a_i, a_{i+1}$?

Comment: Yes, the circle passing through the mentioned points which contains all other points of our convex polygon.

Comment: So the circle is not an empty circle

Comment: @user251257 Yes they do. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcircle.html

Comment: @JoshChen ah. Sorry. I have the wrong image in my mind

Comment: Happens to me all the time!

Comment: The claim is that there are at least two different circles, each containing three consecutive nodes on such circle. Proving that there is at least one such circle could be a good start.

Comment: @Moti Yes yes, it's correct. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Not yet. For a quadrilateral it is obvious and true - there are two circles out of the four that make it. You may try proof by induction. the claim is that out of the n possible different circles (assuming no cases of more than 3 nodes - note that a case of 4 consecutive points is a proper answer) at least two are containing all the points. In quadrilateral there are 4 possible circles. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Moti Yes yes, thanks! lets try!

Comment: @Moti , now the main question is how to prove that the last vertex also should belong to those circles?

Comment: The last vertex may be or may be not forcing the need of a new circle. It depends where in the overlap of the circles the additional vertex is placed. Also, to prove that it is part of a sequence... one key part is that three vertices that define a circle create an obtuse angle

Comment: I posted a proof of the existence of one such index on this (nearly duplicate) question but that argument is based on the largest circumradius and doesn't obviously extend to produce the second index: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742400/prove-that-the-circle-contains-the-polygon/3964485#3964485

Comment: It looks like the title is from another question...